# Reading/Writing .properties file in JBoss causes exceptions

Tags: java, jboss, apache-commons

Currently I am developing a web based application which will be deployed on a variety of java web application containers. The code Ive written to read/write .properties files is using apache commons, the code can be seen below;

```
FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<PropertiesConfiguration> builder = configs.propertiesBuilder(PATH_TO_PROPERTIES);
..update some properties

builder.save();
```

Unfortunately an exception is thrown stating that I was unable to write to vfs:/...... I assume the Apache Commons is not handling vfs, has anyone encountered this before? How can it be commonly resolved to support multiple types of application servers?

```
18:51:31,317 ERROR [com.company.pkg.PropertiesUtil] (default task-31) Unable to update properties: org.apache.commons.configuration2.ex.ConfigurationException: Could not save to URL vfs:/content/MyApplication.war/WEB-INF/classes/config.properties
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.DefaultFileSystem.getOutputStream(DefaultFileSystem.java:97)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileHandler.save(FileHandler.java:1214)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileHandler.save(FileHandler.java:1163)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.FileHandler.save(FileHandler.java:805)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.builder.FileBasedConfigurationBuilder.save(FileBasedConfigurationBuilder.java:240)
.....
Caused by: java.net.UnknownServiceException: protocol doesn't support output
at java.net.URLConnection.getOutputStream(URLConnection.java:843)
at org.apache.commons.configuration2.io.DefaultFileSystem.getOutputStream(DefaultFileSystem.java:86)
... 94 more
```

Comment: Why do you need update file, which is content of WAR archive? You should never update this file, because the next deployment and application restart will overwrite it with content present in clean WAR package. If you need update file, move it outside of WAR, eg. to standalone/configuration folder. Otherwise combine FileConfiguration to CompositeConfiguration and then updates will be kept in memory

Comment: Having configuration files within the war is not unheard of, with a tomcat deployment this is a very common approach. I understand that with jboss the exploded war directory is overwritten during every start/stop. Do you know of a common approach to solve this problem with jboss web application server?

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this?